# How to add Image without this white background?

Tags: android, android-xml, vector-graphics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowKQ.png)

Here it is a XML file,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff2f2"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/tick"
        android:id="@+id/image2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Mainactivity.java,
  item2List.add(new Items2(R.drawable.checked));

Comment: what you want to be instead of that white background?

Comment: Use a `.png` file with no background

Comment: is your img  png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color of CardView is White. If you want to change it to some other color use following code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

or you can set cardBackgroundColor to transparent(if you don't want any color) by setting cardBackgroundColor as

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Where should I add this line?

Comment: Add it in CardView XML tag  as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Set `app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"` instead of `app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff2f2"`.

This will take background of  your Image rather than force white background.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have no idea about your image is .png or .jpeg, but if your image is not .png then take .png image and if you have already taken .png image than set cardview background transparent.

Here, use the `cardBackgroundColor` attribute to remove color and set transparent and `cardElevation` attribute to remove the drop shadow.

Please try below:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent" >
```

If you you use **API level 21 and higher** and in case of `cardBackgroundColor` not work properly you can use `android:backgroundTint`. In my case it works.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent">
```